# wp_mail in pluggable.php return path original settings

Tags: plugins

My server was not providing the correct return path in the source header when WordPress is sending email causing me to fall on blacklists.

I fixed this by adding this string to wp-includes/pluggable.php and I know this could be overwritten on updates so I will create a plugin for it later and simply include this in the plugin

What I do not understand is WP wasn't even getting my FQDN, it seems like it was getting my hostname but not the full hostname -f full name.  Force instance usually a default host would be localhost.localdomain and WP was picking up virtual.localdomain and my FQDN does start with virtual.*

In the email it would be set for whatever email was in general settings, but in the source header the return-path email was built as username@virtual.localdomain.

the username was not even a user in WP it was a linux user I use as administration for this virtual domain.

This is for my own curiosity and understand.  Where is WP getting this from?  I could't trace it...

I should also point out my env is this:

```
Centos7
Webmin version 1.940
Usermin version|1.780
Virtualmin version 6.08
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: the server name is read in $_SERVER : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L320

Comment: Are you sure it's WordPress? I'd guess this would be added by the SMTP server that WordPress uses to send emails, and that's one that you're running locally that was installed and configured by your linux distro.

Comment: Have you done any email configuration in WordPress? Do you have an MTA on your server, e.g. sendmail or postfix? It may have been installed by default. I still think that WordPress is routing email through a local sendmail and that sendmail is adding whatever headers you're looking for.